# PC restarts during power failure, though having an UPS

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer

I have a pc with following specifications:
Ryzen 5 3600
Nvidia geforce gtx 1050ti
16gb ram and 1Tb storage
Antec atom 450w psu
Apc 600va ups (360w)

During normal normal usage and power failure, my computer doesn't restart. But while gaming and power failure it's restarting.
I expect the hold up time of smps is very low. Does mu assumption correct, will a good smps solve my problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

your UPS is rated for 360w and your powersupply is rated for 450w.

When gaming, your GPU and CPU are utilized to high levels drawing more power. It is likely that your powerdrain is more than the UPS can handle, and that causes the computer to reboot.

The only way to not make it reboot is to either ensure you don't draw more than 360 watts or to replace the UPS with one that is capable of delivering the same amount or more than the power supply is drawing.

It is good to consider the following:

A UPS battery usually only lasts for about 5 years before it has to be replaced. If you are close to this time, replacing the entire UPS for a stronger one is a smart choice.

When a UPS is rated for the same as the PSU and the PSU is used at max, the UPS will  not be able to keep the computer running for long. It can take a very short power interruption, but if it lasts for more than a few minutes, the computer is likely to  turn off anyway. If your goal is to keep the computer running for at least half an hour, get a beefy UPS that is rated for 1000 watts or more.

Also, if your UPS has a management port, usually USB, and you connect this to your computer, you can setup a script using task scheduler to automatically set your computer to an extreme low power management setting, limiting your CPU to really slow settings. It will not allow you to game, but your screen will likely turn off anyway, but it will keep your computer up and running for way longer.

To give you an indication, I've setup this on my home computer and I can activate it on the fly by pressing a button. High performance gives me about 300 watt of power draw while being in windows, and about 40 watts when I set it to super low energy. While in super low energy mode, I can still watch youtube videos well, only gaming is not really that smart.

Comment: get a beefy UPS that is rated for 1000 watts or more.  ...  Agree.  Also get a true UPS and not a battery eliminator.  +1